# AS400 DB2 national characters into SQL Server linked server

Tags: sql-server, db2, linked-server, db2-400

I have a SQL Server 2012 Enterprise edition linked server connection to an IBM AS400 DB2 database.
I am using the `IBMDASQL` provider for the connection.

I have problems with some Hungarian characters: the letter `Ő` is converting to `O` during the select.

In this example the `name_converted` column will be OK, the `Ő` letter remains `Ő`.

The name column will be converted to `O`.

```
SELECT * FROM openquery (g,
   SELECT 
       cast(name as char(35) ccsid 870) as name_converted,
       name,
   FROM libr.mytable')
```

My question is: can I create the linked server so that all the character is using the CCSID 870?

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'G', @srvproduct = N'HUN00101', @provider  = N'IBMDASQL', @datasrc = N'HUN00101'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'G', @useself=N'False', 
            @locallogin=NULL, @rmtuser=N'query', @rmtpassword='########' 
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server = N'G', @optname = N'collation compatible', 
                                @optvalue = N'false' 
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'G', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true' GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'G', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false' GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'G', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false' GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'G', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'false' GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'G', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'false' GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'G', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false' GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'G', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0' GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'G', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'G', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false' GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'G', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0' GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'G', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true' GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'G', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true' GO
```

Thanks

Comment: On this link: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=151072      I found Host CCSID=37;PC Code Page=850. Can I build it somehow into the Linked servers connection?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the data may not have been properly tagged with CCSID 870 on the IBM i system.   Can you try using the "Force Translate" custom property and setting it to 870? 
Note: This will cause all data not properly tagged with a CCSID to be handled as CCSID 870.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The "Force Translate" option is on AS400 side or it is on SQL Server?

Comment: My guess is that you would set it like the following:  EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'G', @optname=N'Force Translate', @optvalue=N'870' GO

Comment: Unfortunately there are no option 'Force Translate' for the sp_serveroption procedure: [link] http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SP_SERVEROPTION_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true

Comment: Try using @provstr=N'Force Translate=870' with sp_addlinkedserver.

Comment: I inserted your suggestion into the command, but unfortunately it is still not ok. EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'G', @srvproduct=N'HUN00101', @provider=N'IBMDASQL', @datasrc=N'HUN00101',@provstr=N'Force Translate=870'